# Getting Users and their Roles .NET 8 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-applications, .net-8.0

I'm trying to get users from a particular company and their Roles.

```
public IndexModel( UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
     _userManager = userManager;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
     ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
     ValidatePermission Validate = new ValidatePermission(_context, _userManager);

     if (!await Validate.validateAdmin(user))
     {
         return RedirectToPage("/InvalidPermissions");
     }

     var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
     var users =  _userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Company_ID == user.Company_ID).Where(u => u.Id != user.Id);

     Users = new List<CompanyUserViewModel>();

     foreach (var companyUser in users)
     {
         var tempUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(companyUser.Id);
         var userRoles =  await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(tempUser);
         CompanyUserViewModel userView = new CompanyUserViewModel();
         userView.ID = companyUser.Id;
         userView.Name = companyUser.FirstName + " " + companyUser.LastName;
         userView.Role = userRoles.Contains("Admin") ? "Admin" : userRoles.Contains("Manager") ? "Manager" : "User";
         userView.JobTitle = companyUser.JobTitle;
         userView.Email = companyUser.Email;
         Users.Add(userView);
     }
     return Page();
}
```

However this returns an error

> InvalidOperationException: This MySqlConnection is already in use

Comment: you seem to be using the items of `users` (which isn't resolved yet) to fetch something again. Try applying `.ToList()` where you are fetching users. Although, please keep in mind that ToList() is going to get all the items in memory which could cause performance issue

Comment: You are adding the object userview to the users : [Users.Add(userView);].  The object is not being released.  So next time you attempt to create a new object with new CompanyUserViewModel() the object is locked.  Easiest solution is to make it a list : List<CompanyUserViewModel> userView = new List<CompanyUserViewModel>()

Comment: Within your code, instead of creating a new connection in each iteration of the foreach loop, establish a single connection at the beginning of the method and dispose of it at the end using the using statement, you should use your DbContext in order to keep it seperate. Becase, the error indicating the connection that is already being used or has not been properly released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However this returns an error
>
> InvalidOperationException: This MySqlConnection is already in use

Well based on your code and error message indicates that multiple operation trying to use the connection pool together while the previous connection has not been released.

This error typically occurs when you attempt to use a MySqlConnection object that is already being used by another operation. In ASP.NET Core applications, Entity Framework Core manages the connection pool, so you generally don't need to manually manage connections.

So in summery, you are trying multiple data retrieval commands executed on single connection. This could happend, when you iterate through result of the [query (IQueryable)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying) and you will trigger lazy loading for loaded entity inside the iteration.

Let's investigate your code, in order to pin point the issue. Although, it would nicer, if you could share your code in a ways so that we could reproducible. However, its hard to say exactly what causing the issue.

It seems your methods is asynchronous, so at the first glimps, I can see, you are getting `users` and without specifying its type, you are directly executing the loop. See the following line:

```
var users =  _userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Company_ID == user.Company_ID).Where(u => u.Id != user.Id);
```

But for executing loop you have to let the list been populate first. So your pool still engaged there.

Instead Of doing that, you should use populate an asynchronous list of users.
You could do as following:

```
var users = await _userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Company_ID == user.Company_ID && u.Id != user.Id).ToListAsync();
```

Therefore, if you use `ToListAsync()` your previous operation just releases the conection and open for new execution.

Another issue is your DbContext. I can see you are using `_context` from where it has not been shown or clarified. If you are using the context from somewhere, its important to check, whether the connnection disposed there. But its always wise to inject the connection through the constructor. So you can initialize your DbContext through the constructor as following:

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public IndexModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _context = context;
    }
```

In addition, I don't see any uses of following call:

```
var tempUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(companyUser.Id);
```

As you have companyUser collection, why don't you directly get what you need from that. So, I think, you could get rid of that.

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying), if you want to study more on this.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, that worked! Because it was failing at population of "userRoles" I thought it must have been the line populating "tempUser" however adding to list fixed this. I couldn't use ToListAsync as the foreach loop through errors.

Comment: Glad to assist you on this and happy to know your issue has been resolved.